# Mysql table name not working in uppercase

Tags: mysql

I need to change mysql is accept both uppercase and lowercase table name ,

```
select * from users
```

the above query working fine but the below query is not working,

```
select * from USERS
```

Comment: Table names are case sensitive on any file system that's case sensitive. Either change FS (or more likely OS), or use the proper identified. Really, you should be using the proper identifiers. It's strange/confusing otherwise.

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). This varies from OS to OS and filesystem to filesystem.

Comment: I strongly recommend to always use lowercase names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on your system (Unix, Windows and Mac OS for the main values).

You need to set your system variable "lower_case_table_names" to 1 or 2, to make your database case insensitive.

```
SET lower_case_table_names=1;
```

or

```
SET lower_case_table_names=2;
```

click at [Mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: This answer is very misleading.  This variable is only used at the `Create Table` statement.

Comment: Beware of the Incorrect Answer. lower_case_table_names=2, Documnetation says "Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not case-sensitive! InnoDB table names are stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1."

Answer (score 10):

**windows = lowercase.**

I do not recommend changing the mysqld config to 0 or 2.

- **lower_case_table_names = 0    (comparisons are case-sensitive)**
  If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case-sensitive.
- lower_case_table_names = 1    (comparisons are not case-sensitive)
  If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive.
- **lower_case_table_names = 2    (comparisons are case-sensitive)**
  If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase.

If you want to change it, find my.ini file in windows usually mysql directory, in wamp check the bin directory and add the "lower_case_table_names = 0" or "lower_case_table_names = 2"

This option also applies to database names and table aliases.
Reference to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Answer (score 0):

Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE DATABASE` statement. Name comparisons are case sensitive. You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file names (such as Windows or Mac OS X). If you force this variable to 0 with **--lower-case-table-names=0** on a case-insensitive file system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption may result.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

```
In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. 
Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database
directory. Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system 
plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names.
```

Read the section: [8.2.2. Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

But to solve your problem, you could create a view of the table setting the name as the different case.  But then what happens to `users`

Answer (score 0):

One option can be setting all the table names to either lower or upper as per your OS needs.

```
select concat('rename table ', table_name, ' to ' , lower(table_name) , ';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'your_schema_name';
```

copy all the lines and execute them :)

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages trying to resolve this, where all other SQL queries were working without issue on my system.

As it turns out, I'd added the new table I was looking for into a different database by accident (working on a different project).

I recommend just double check you're looking for the right table, in the right database, in the right domain... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your SQL tables created in either Uppercase or camelCase, do the following.

**Step 1:** open your MySQL `my.ini` configuration file:

=> [**Linux**]\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

=> [**Windows**]C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

=> [**xampp**] click on mysql -> config then open my.ini file

**Step 2:** Search [mysqld] in my.ini file

**Step 3:** Add this `lower_case_table_names=2`

**Step 4:** save the file and restart MySQL service or (Xampp)

You can now create SQL Tables in case sensitive format.