# TypeORM throws QueryFailedError Table already exists on MySQL when synchronize is true

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using NestJS, TypeORM, and MySQL to build a web application.

I am using a `.env` file to pass in some environment variables for connecting to my local database. Synchronize is set to `true`.

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: '.env' }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                type: 'mysql',
                host: configService.get('TYPEORM_HOST'),
                port: configService.get('TYPEORM_PORT'),
                username: configService.get('TYPEORM_USERNAME'),
                password: configService.get('TYPEORM_PASSWORD'),
                database: configService.get('TYPEORM_DATABASE'),
                autoLoadEntities: true,
                synchronize: configService.get('TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE'),
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

In addition, I have a Users module which imports a user entity.

**users.module.ts**

```
import { User } from './Entities/User.entity';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature(
        [User]
    )],
    controllers: [UsersController],
    providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

**User.entity.ts**

```
@Entity({ name: "Users"})
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    userName: string;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;
}
```

Assuming, my database is empty, when starting up the application for the very first time, TypeORM synchronization will automatically create the User table for me with the appropriate columns and data types. However, when closing the application and trying to restart, I get this error:

```
[Nest] 14876   - 06/17/2020, 12:37:33 PM   [ExceptionHandler] Table 'users' already exists +3ms
QueryFailedError: Table 'users' already exists
    at new QueryFailedError (C:\MyProject\Server\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.onResult (C:\MyProject\Server\node_modules\typeorm\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.js:170:45)
    at Query.execute (C:\MyProject\Server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:14)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (C:\MyProject\Server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:417:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket C:\MyProject\Server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\MyProject\Server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\MyProject\Server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:278:9)
```

If I then turn synchronization off and start it up again, I get the same error. My only workaround is to drop the `users` table, turn synchronization back on in order to recreate it and then turn it back off. Is there a reason why TypeORM tries to re-create a table that already exists? For ease-of-use, I'd like to not have to always remember to toggle synchronization every time.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Hyra10 no, since I've moved on to another issue soon after posting this. If you ever figure it out, please post the answer here.

Comment: I'm also having this issue but although I gives me that exception too, I just restart de server and runs with success. And the table is also created in the database, and read to be used.  Stranger things.

Answer (score 7):

For me the solution was to change the name of the database in the config of TypOrmModule to lowercase to match the created schema on the mysql server.

For some reason it's allowed to be different on first setup of TypeOrm.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I tried all the answers in this post but nothing worked.

This was my entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Photo {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ length: 500 })
    name: string;
}
```

This created a table called *photo* with the schema *public*.

What fixed it for me was actually providing the table name and the schema :

```
@Entity({ name: 'photo', schema: 'public' })
export class Photo {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ length: 500 })
    name: string;
}
```

For some reason the *synchronize* feature of TypeORM has a problem if the table is uppercase and if the schema is not set. After setting the schema and the table name (lower case) it worked with `synchronize: true`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was caused by

```
  synchronize: true
  migrationsRun: true
```

in

typeOrmConfig

It should be only synchronize or migrationsRun set to true, not both

Comment: I have only synchronize set to true and I still get this error

Comment: DO NOT use ``synchronize: true`` in production!!!

Answer (score 2):

I can almost guarantee you that issue has to do with your entity name being uppercase i.e.

> @Entity({ name: "Users"})

TypeORM doesn't seem to like this an should rather use:

> @Entity({ name: "users"})

Have a look at this thread for more info
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4420

Answer (score 2):

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'gy0601xq',
      database: 'mydev',
      entities: [Coffee, Flavor],
      synchronize: true,
      dropSchema: true,//this option maybe helpful
    }
```

Drops the schema each time connection is being established. Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise you'll lose all production data. This option is useful during debug and development.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `dist` folder solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I just set the migrationsRun to false on my `ormconfig.ts` file and it worked.

```
synchronize: false,
migrationsRun: false,
```

I think this issue is caused by the orm trying to automatically run migrations when we have already done it manually.

Comment: Do you have a example? And just have database config connection in this file. This file is a object array.

Comment: Can confirm. `migrationsRun: false` helped also in my case. In my case I tried to restart the server via pm2 on a digital ocean droplet and since the migration was already executed before via migrationsRun setting to true a restart didn't help and cause the already exists error. For now I've set the flag to `false` and will do migrations manually in the future until I know about another way around this

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and I solved it finally, what I found was I had set synchronize to false at first and then true and did some tests, created/generated migrations keeping synchronize true. I also had some migrations generated but not applied. Later I set synchronize to false and when I tried to apply migration, it gave me error like you mentioned. I think the unapplied piles of generated migrations gave me the issues.

So, for me what solved the issue is, I deleted all the migration files and then regenerated the migration and applied that migration.  That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error.
I tried everything:

- reduce entities/tables to a minimum
- change TypeOrm options (synchronize, autoLoadEntites, entities, migrationsRun,...)
- moved TypeOrm configuration into main.ts or .json
- updated MySQL version (including a complete removal on MAC)
- re-initialized the entire project with new versions of nestJS and TypeOrm

=> Conclusion: with "synchronize":true it never worked when the tables already existed. But for development you really want that feature to be enabled...

=> I had installed 'mysql2' (see package.json), because 'mysql' did not work with my MySQL (setup). I always got an AUTHENTICATION ERROR with mysql.

=> **Solution**: Use 'mysql' (not 2) and - if it doesn't work (AUTH ERROR) - re-install (or configure manually) MySQL (newest version) and select old authentication method during install.

Hope that helps (I did not find this solution anywhere). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just set

```
@Entity({ name: 'User' })
export class User {...}
```

instead

```
@Entity()
export class User {...}
```

and 'Oh magic', error come out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `synchronize : true` was causing this error .

`synchronize` information says it should be set to false on production :

Indicates if database schema should be auto created on every application launch. Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise you can lose production data. This option is useful during debug and development. Alternative to it, you can use CLI and run schema:sync command.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while, but a possible cause could be you've not added an entities glob? https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/using-environment-variables

```
  entities: '*.entity.ts',
```

I think that should shove the issues as it'll create an entities map. If not try dropping the table, let it create it and then try sync again?

Answer (score 0):

rebuild your app before running the migration
i.e
run `nest build` or `yarn build` depending on how you set the command in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

If all the other answers don't help, for me the issue was I copied a model and forgot to change the name!

Silly mistake but don't have 2 models with the same name :D

```
@Entity({ name: "users"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **MySql** as a database.

**My issue was related to the name of entities.**

#### All letters of the table name should be lowercase

In my case, the table name is `proclamationHistory` but does not work.

```
@Entity ({name: "proclamationHistory"})
export class ProclamationHistoryEntity {
  ...
}
```

It worked when I changed the name to `proclamationhistory` or `proclamation_history`

check out the name of all entities in your project to be lowercase.

**NOTE**: I did not have this problem with **PostgreSQL**.

**Please checkout** [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795947/mysql-table-name-not-working-in-uppercase)

[Mysql table name not working in uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795947/mysql-table-name-not-working-in-uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Check TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
   ...,
   ....,
   database: 'test', //**All lower case**
   entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
   synchronize: true,
   })
2. Keep @Entity() empty.

Those works for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the solution is that the object name should be write in lowercase

```
@Entity('profileSkills') // don't work for me
export class ProfileSkillsEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}


@Entity('profile-skills') // solve my problem
export class ProfileSkillsEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
}
```

also check that your name of database, it should be in lowercase too.

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=testDb // don't know but don't work for me

MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb // solved my issue
```

in `app.module.ts` should be

```
{
...
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    ...
    logging: true,
    migrationsRun: false,
    synchronize: true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i import databaseProvider twice

```
// database.module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { databaseProviders } from "./database.provider";

@Module({
  providers: [...databaseProviders],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}

// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

i remove databaseProvider in `app.module.ts` and it work

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else struggling with this `synchronize: true` alone did not the job for me and I had to add `dropSchema: true`.

Note that those settings are meant to be use for development purposes only, using those on production will make you lose data 100%. Use `migrations` instead.

Answer (score 0):

nestjs don't remove all files of dist folder when do rebuild with start:dev, for solve this issue you can do this thinks:

- delete dist folder and rebuild project
- set synchronize to false (if you want to create another entity you need to do fist option)

Is so probably u have 2 User.entity.js in dist folder.

(sorry if are some orthography error)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me

```
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(
        {
            type: 'mysql',
            host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
            port: +process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
            username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
            database: database, // database name should be lowercase
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            synchronize: true,
            migrationsRun: false
        }),
```

and

```
@Entity({ name: 'accounts' }) // table name should be lowercase
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  synchronize: true,
  migrationsRun: true,
}
```

Removing both makes it works on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by placing your code inside a try catch block

Then in the catch block you check the error code and if it is of type "Dubplicate key" you handle it

Here is my example:

```
export const createUser= async(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
    try {
        const newUser= await AppDataSource.getRepository(User).save(req.body)
        return res.json(newUser)
    } catch (error) {
        if( error.code=="ER_DUP_ENTRY"){
            return res.status(500).json({msg:"Registro duplicado"})
        }
        return res.status(500).json(error.code)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> @Module({   imports: [
> ConfigModule.forRoot({
> isGlobal: true,
> }),
> // TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
> //   autoLoadEntities: true,
> // }),
> TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
> type: process.env.DB_TYPE as any,
> host: process.env.DB_HOST,
> port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
> username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
> password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
> database: process.env.DB_NAME,
> // entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
> synchronize: true,
>
> ```
>   migrations run: true,
>   //   type: 'MySQL',
>   //   host: 'localhost',
>   //   username: 'root',
>   //   password: null,
>   //   database: 'aa',
>   entities: [Task, User],
>   dropSchema: true, //this option may be helpful
>   // entities: ['../Typeform*emphasized text*/entities/*.ts'],
>
>   //   synchronize: true, that in when was false make problem   }),
> UsersModule,
> TaskModule,
> AuthModule,   ],   controllers: [],   providers: [], }) export class AppModule {}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i face the same issue . please check once did u write database name in lowercase . In my case I just changed it all lowercase and my issue get solved .(when u synchronize :true )

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening when the application cannot read the migration from the migrations table.

I checked checked my postgres database and saw that for the database user "application" my migration table was completely empty.

Because of typeorm reads the migration tale and sees that the migration table is empty, it is trying to execute migration:run script.

In order to fix it first I copied migrations table of another user of the database (in my case the public user) andgrant all the permissions for the user and changed the owner to the application.

For changing the ownership [this github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3107#issuecomment-568468351) comment helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Write all letters in lower case. just change the "Users" to "users"

```
@Entity({ name: "Users"}) <<<<<<<<<<<< HERE: "Users" to "user"
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    userName: string;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;
}
```

Comment: `Users` to `users` (as the text says) or `Users` to `user` (as the comment says)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by removing special characters from a table name:

Renaming "db.name" => "db_name" solved the issue in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

making `synchronize: false` worked for me.
However, with this approach is, it won't create a table automatically anymore. It assumes that the table already exists.

Comment: first i had synchronize set false and then later i set it true for some days and did some coding, and then again set it to false, now i created migration and run it but says xyz relation already exists. is this expected and why?